# submenu alone works perfect till u add it to a menu

Tags: css, menu, submenu

I have a sub menu that by it self looks and works perfectly. But when I add it to the main menu it messes up.

It is designed to have a few features
1.uses no height or width so u can add or subtract as many LI's as u want and it still works.
2.when the browser is shrunk it will not go off screen it will just make 2,3,4 rows accordingly and collapse the div.
here is the sub menu by itself:
http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/950/
 as u can see when u shrink or expand the page it stays uniformed.

when u add it as a sub menu to the main menu it messes up
http://jsfiddle.net/vMuxA/948/
IM assuming I have a > selector needed somewhere can anyone tell me what im doing wrong?
 I want the submenu to work in the menu like it does by itself.

```css
#navagation{
float:left;
width:100%;
height:100%;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
#btmenu{
border: 1px solid green;
z-index:1;
position:relative;
width:100%;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:62px;
text-align:center;
}
ul#btmenu li{ 
padding:0;
margin:0;
display: inline;
}
#btmenu li > a{ height:62px;
line-height:62px;
margin-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
text-decoration:none;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:15px;
color:#000;
padding-left:1%;
padding-right:1%;
text-transform:uppercase;
vertical-align: middle;
}
#btmenu > li > a:hover{
background-color:#333;
color:#FFF; 
}


/*     SUB MENU     */
.sub_menu{
display:none;
}
#btmenu > li:hover .sub_menu{
position:absolute;
display:inline-block;/*no need for height or width*/
vertical-align: middle;
margin:0 auto;
text-align:center;
background-color:#666;
border: 1px solid red;
list-style: none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
display:table;
}
.sub_menu li{
margin:5px;
display:inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
.sub_menu li a{
display:block;
vertical-align: middle;
background-color:#F00;
height:100px;
width:100px;margin:0;
padding:0;
text-decoration:none;
color:#FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="navagation">
<ul id="btmenu">

<li class="top_quote"><a href="services">services</a>

<ul class="sub_menu">
<li class="auto body repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="rental & loaner"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="hail damage repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="towing"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="glass repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="glass repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="glass repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="glass repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
<li class="glass repair"><a href="#"><img src="http://s33.postimg.org/dkznchu73/test_image.png" width="100" height="100"></a></li>
</ul>

</li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="locations">locations</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="partners">partners</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="our work">our work</a></li>
<li class="top_quote"><a href="contact">contact</a></li>




</ul>
</div><!--navagation-->
```

Comment: Consider adding padding or margins.

Comment: there is already a 5px margin around each submenu LI